# What does "Vous êtes en cinquième." mean?

Tags: éducation

It is in relation to the French educational system.
But fifth what?

Answer (score 4):

"*Cinquième*" would correspond to the seventh grade in the US but the system is different in France and in the US. In the US, 1st grade is our "CP" ("*cours préparatoire*"), and they count going up, but we count going down starting at "sixième" which is the US "*6th grade*".

For "école primaire", we have:

- CP ▶  US 1st grade
- CE1 (*cours élémentaire 1*)
- CE2
- CM1 (*cours moyen 1*)
- CM2 ▶  US 5th grade

For "collège" we have:

- sixième (6e) ▶  US 6th grade
- cinquième (5e)
- quatrième (4e)
- troisième (3e) ▶  US 9th grade

Then "lycée" is:

- seconde ▶  US 10th grade
- première
- terminale ▶  US 12th grade

More details [here](http://photos.state.gov/libraries/france/5/pa/grade-level-comparison.pdf).

After that, it is pretty complicated, with options not quite available in the US. That would deserve another post.

Answer (score 0):

It's the French denomination for "7th grade".

We count down from 12th grade, which marks the end of [secondary education](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_education) after a big and important exam, the *baccalauréat* or "[*bac*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baccalaur%C3%A9at)".

It's a little weird but it kind of makes sense to us. Basically, if you're in *cinquième* you have 5 years left before you finish your studies (or before you go to University).